is it something affected if we install dependency in main project which is part of custom library angular

I have created one Angular library lib1;
I have created one Angular Application App1;
I have installed lib1 in my App1

Suppose I have used some npm package(moment) in lib1;
Now i have requirement that i have to use that npm package(moment) in App1 so i have installed it via npm install moment in App1

is it proper way to do that?

is it will affect build size?

Or should i export moment package from lib1 and import that package from lib1 into App1?



You could add the package(moment) as peer dependency to lib1 and install it in App1.

how can i install that package in app1?

npm install moment. You've tagged the question with Angular. You should know how peer dependencies work. Angular uses this feature for most dependencies, e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/package.json#L23
